# PHP set the attribute for an image with matrix values

Tags: php, image, matrix, attributes

as the topic,I need to set the attribute for an image or create an image with the attribute what I get from a client as the matrix values.
I found a function named imageconvolution,but it doesn't work out.Maybe I used it incorrectly.
here is the code:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromgif('http://www.php.net/images/php.gif');

$emboss = array(array(0, 0, 100), array(0, 0, 200), array(0, 0, 1));
imageconvolution($image, $emboss, 1, 0);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image, null, null);
?>
```

the matrix values are used to scale or rotate or move the image.Is these code right?
I hope to find out someone to teach me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling, rotation and moving are affine transforms. You cannot use convolution for this matrixes.
I think the easiest way to use the php Imagick extension. It has an affineTransformImage function which you can use: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.affinetransformimage.php

Comment: Could you show me a simple sample to use it?I'm not good at PHP. I'm good at android and I need to find out the matrix whether can be used in PHP.I'm appreciated.

Comment: I find a function called ImagickDraw::affine, we can put these matrix values into array.Is it right?